# Can i use only an app's .apk to automate using appium? Or i need the app in my workspace?

Tags: android, eclipse, webdriver, appium

I am asking this because when i automate an app(TestApp.apk) present in my workspace is working fine. But when i use another app(WnG.apk) which is not present in my workspace it doesn't works. At this time appium fails to locate the element. An error ("**An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.**") occurs.

Below is my code:

public class Appium {

```
WebDriver driver;

@BeforeClass
public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Android Emulator");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, ""); //Name of mobile web browser to automate. Should be an empty string if automating an app instead.
    capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "4.4");
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Windows");
    capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
    capabilities.setCapability("app", "C:/Appium/AppiumForWindows-1.2.4.1/WishAndGreet.apk");
    capabilities.setCapability("app-package", "com.example.wishandgreet"); //Replace with your app's package
    capabilities.setCapability("app-activity", ".LoginActivity"); //Replace with app's Activity
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
}

@Test
public void loginTest(){
    System.out.println("*************************************************************");
    WebElement e1 = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.wishandgreet:id/usernameEditText"));

    System.out.println(e1.getText());
    Assert.assertTrue(e1.getText() == "email / mobile number", "Username Text incorrect");
    //Assert.assertEquals(e1.getText(),"email / mobile number");
    e1.sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
    WebElement e2 = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.wishandgreet:id/passwordEditText"));

    Assert.assertTrue(e2.getText() == "Password", "Pass text incorrect");
    e2.sendKeys("1234");
    System.out.println(e2);
    WebElement e3 = driver.findElement(By.id("com.example.wishandgreet:id/loginButton"));
    e3.click();

    System.out.println(e1);
}

@AfterClass
public void tearDown(){
    driver.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android case, you need only .apk file to automate using Appium.
Looks like the issue you are facing is related to identifying an element. Please double check you are using right locators to identify required element and make sure that element appears on the view.

Comment: @Surya-I have caught the problem, actually on the app launch a "Google Play Service" pop up appears, so appium can't locate the element on that pop up.Well Thanks for your help:)

Comment: That's good. Thanks for the update. Will you mind in accepting this as answer? As it answers your query and it will be helpful for any one else having this doubt/query.

Comment: @Surya-How can i handle this pop up as i have got its button id(android:id/button1) and set .click() at top of my code, but still appium is unable to locate this element.

Comment: Try with driver.switchTo().alert().accept()/dismiss()